# Naming terminal monosubstituted alkenes conformations

Tags: nomenclature

Alkenes can be described by E/Z nomenclature and cis/trans nomenclature.

However, is there a way to name alkene conformations which are monosubstituted? For example, how could one describe the difference between the following conformations?

Any suggestions are welcome, even if they aren't IUPAC accepted -- I would just like to hear what the community thinks would be a good way to differentiate these type of structures.

[image]

Comment: Huh, you mean like s-cis / s-trans?

Comment: Awesome thanks! It slipped my mind. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Only if you want, perhaps there more to be added ,or this can work as sort of redirect. Duplicates are often useful.